# How to generate random latitude and longitude in a city using java?

Tags: java, random, latitude-longitude

How can I generate a random location (latitude and longitude) *within* a city using `Java`?

I want to test application functionality with random locations within a city (a single city for now).

Comment: see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: If this is Android related, developers options provide fake positions.

Comment: @user3505725,my problem is not generating random number, is generate random latitude and longitude in a city.

Comment: @ Djon, it is java app not an android app

Comment: Isn't latitude and longitude are of type numbers??

Comment: Are you hunting for a geographic definition for city boundaries so your "random" location lies within the city? How many cities do you want to do this for?  One (brute force) strategy you could use is to determine whether an circle or a square best 'covers' the city; generate a candidate point by using radian, radius for circle, or x,y from lower left of square .. then use Google Maps API to see if that long/lat lies within the "city" (governmental enclosure); repeat if not.

Comment: @ user3505725, I know they are long, my problem is to generate number in city lat lng boundry!

Comment: @ErstwhileIII , for now I need for one city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Google Maps "Reverse Geocoding" to help see if a random location is within a city.

Consider the following partial code demo:

**TestRandomCityLocations Main**

```
package com.example.mapping;

import java.util.Random;

public class TestRandomCityLocation {
    // Class fields
    private static TestRandomCityLocation me;
    private static final String[] defaultArguments = { "" };

    // Object fields

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arguments;

        me = new TestRandomCityLocation();
        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            arguments = defaultArguments;
        } else {
            arguments = args;
        }

        me.doWork(arguments);

    }

    private void doWork(String[] arguments) {
        int maximumPoints = 100;
        GeographicPoint newLocation;

        GeographicSquare mockCityGeo = new GeographicSquare(
                new GeographicPoint(38.7, -77.0), new GeographicPoint(38.9,
                        -76.9));
        String cityName = "Google Maps city name";

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        double deltaLong = mockCityGeo.getDeltaLongitude();
        double deltaLat = mockCityGeo.getDeltaLatitude();

        for (int i = 0; i < maximumPoints; i++) {
            newLocation = new GeographicPoint(
                    mockCityGeo.getLowerLeftLatitude() + deltaLat
                            * randomGenerator.nextDouble(),
                    mockCityGeo.getLowerLeftLongitude() + deltaLong
                            * randomGenerator.nextDouble());

            // TODO test to see of newLocation is in the city
            if (GoogleMapInfo.isWithinCity(cityName, newLocation)) {
                // TODO Do something
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**GeographicSquare Class**

```
package com.example.mapping;

public class GeographicSquare {
    // Object fields
    private GeographicPoint lowerLeft;
    private GeographicPoint upperRight;
    public GeographicSquare (GeographicPoint lowerLeft, GeographicPoint upperRight) {
        this.lowerLeft = lowerLeft;
        this.upperRight = upperRight;
    }
    public double getDeltaLongitude() {
        return lowerLeft.getLongitudeDifference(upperRight);
    }
    public double getDeltaLatitude() {
        return lowerLeft.getLatitudeDifference(upperRight);
    }
    public double getLowerLeftLongitude() {
        return lowerLeft.getLongitude();
    }
    public double getLowerLeftLatitude() {
        return lowerLeft.getLatitude();
    }
}
```

**GeographicPoint Class**

```
package com.example.mapping;

public class GeographicPoint {
    // Object fields
    private double latitude; 
    private double longitude;

    public GeographicPoint(double latitudeDegrees, double  longitudeDegrees) {
        this.latitude = latitudeDegrees;
        this.longitude = longitudeDegrees;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    /** Distance calculation using Haversine formula to calculate a great-circle distance 
     * between two points of the surface of the earth.
     * 
     * formula: a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
     * c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
     * d = R ⋅ c
        where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius 
        (mean radius = 3958,756 miles (6,371km));
        Note bene: angles must be in radians to pass to trig functions!
     * @param location
     * @return
     */
    public double milesFrom(GeographicPoint location) {

        double rInMiles = 3958.756;
        double lat1Radians = radiansFromDegrees(latitude);
        double lat2Radians = radiansFromDegrees(location.getLatitude());
        double deltaLat = radiansFromDegrees(location.getLatitude()-latitude);
        double deltaLong = radiansFromDegrees(location.getLongitude()-longitude);

        double a = Math.sin(deltaLat/2.0) * Math.sin(deltaLat/2.0) +
                   Math.cos(lat1Radians) * Math.cos(lat2Radians) * Math.sin(deltaLong/2.0)*Math.sin(deltaLong/2.0);
        double c = 2.0 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        double d = rInMiles * c;

        return d;

    }

    public double getLatitudeDifference(GeographicPoint location) {
        return Math.abs(latitude - location.getLatitude());
    }
    public double getLongitudeDifference(GeographicPoint location) {
        return Math.abs(longitude - location.getLongitude());
    }
    public GeographicPoint getOffsetPoint(double latitudeOffset, double longitudeOffset) {
        return new GeographicPoint(latitude+latitudeOffset, longitude+longitudeOffset);
    }
    // Internal methods

    private double radiansFromDegrees(double degrees) {
        return (degrees * Math.PI) / 180.0;
    }
}
```

**Mock GoogleMapInfo Class**

```
package com.example.mapping;

public class GoogleMapInfo {
    // Consider using Reverse Geocoding in Google Maps api and look at locality political
    // see: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding][1] 


    public static boolean isWithinCity(String cityName,
            GeographicPoint newLocation) {
        // Get governmental info for location and see if the city name matches
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, I will try it. but in XML result, there are too many locality political, how can I access the sufficient one. (I query to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?)